# MySQL access denied for all users, even root

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP script that looks like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "gateway7_make", "$PASSWORD$");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Host information: %s\n", mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
}
```

And this script consistently outputs

```
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'gateway7_make'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Unless I use my webhost password, in which case it outputs

```
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'gateway7_make'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Trying to use "root@localhost" gives me the same message as above.

I know the username and password are valid, because they work with phpmyadmin installed on the same machine.

The script, the mysql server, and phpmyadmin are all on the same Hostmonster server.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try connecting to the ip address of the machine instead of localhost.  Sometimes you need to add separate permissions to be able to connect to mysql via 'localhost'.

Comment: @JoeT, that just gives me the error "Connect failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx ' (110) "

Comment: @bobman321123, yep, I'm stupid today :) Did this ever work or is this new code?

Comment: @Daniel, new code, but connecting via phpmyadmin works without issue.

Comment: To me it sounds like a permission problem. Try and "re-GRANT" and come back with the result. But it is still very strange that it works with phpmyadmin.

Comment: What is with `"$PASSWORD$"`? You know that PHP will try to parse `$PASSWORD` and append a dollar sign to the result (because all this expression is wrapped by *double* quotes), right?

Comment: @inhan, $PASSWORD$ is a placeholder to prevent all you lovely people from knowing my login information.

Comment: @Daniel, I tried running "GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'gateway7_make'@'localhost';". It gave me the error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'gateway7_make'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Have you tried connect by socket to see if you have the same problem?
are you sure phpmyadmin doesn't connect by socket?

Comment: @DaniloKobold, Daniel,  as embarassing a mistake as this is, inhan accidentally stumbled on the error. My real password, which had been replaced by $PASSWORD$ in this example, did indeed start with a $, and was surrounded by double quotes...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was that my password contained a "$", and wasn't surrounded by the proper single quotes.

Thank you all for your assistance and time.